# Retrofit, refactor from FormUrlEncoded to standard Json Body

Tags: android, json, retrofit

My api now accepts true json objects as arguments, before that, I had to use "url encoding" to get there.

For most of my retrofit requests, the translation goes quite smoothly, but I have this one request that borther me :

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/**")
Call<QuestionAnswerResponse> postResponse(
    @Path("id") String id, 
    @Field("self[text]") String text, 
    @Field("self[medias]") List<String> medias);
```

that I want to become :

```
@POST("/api/**")
Call<QuestionAnswerResponse> postResponse(
    @Path("id") String id, 
    @Body ArgType args);
```

I should have in ArgType a `public Map<String, Object> self` ? How to do with this kind of types ?

Thanks,

Comment: depends on how the server expects the json object to be. Probably simply `{ "text": "...", "medias" : [ "..", "..", ...] }`, no self, just those fields.

Comment: nope, He expects self infortunatly (there are more arguments I didn't put, He expects something like ```{key:"value", self:{ "text": "...", "medias" : [ "..", "..", ...] }}```

Comment: but I don't know how to get gson to translate my class like that (beside a custom converter of course)

Comment: Like those two: http://pastebin.com/XyWP5vPH? But I think you can actually use a `Map` like you did. (edit: link broken)

Comment: Of course ! thanks a lot